# Does it give bonus for cutting specific parts of enemies?

Tags: metal-gear-rising-revengeance

I remember that after the first chapter, Raiden and Doktor had a conversation while Raiden was in the stealth jet and Doktor mentioned something about cutting the enemies's left hand for the combat chip inside.

So I have 3 questions:

1. Does it really give any sort of bonus if I cut the left hand off of an enemy?
2. Are there any special bonus if I cut specific parts off of enemy?
3. Does the number of pieces matter when I cut? If not I'd just do one cut and get the fuel cell to be more efficient.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When finishing an enemy, always check for the red hands. Cutting them off gives you a collectible of 50 hands. They contain data which gives you new stuff in the game.

Other than that, feet and hands give you points, cutting too many times will destroy the body and give you 100p once. Cutting through the red highlighted rectangle gives you the possibility of snagging their core and getting full energy on both bars.

Also, cutting through several bodies' cores in one Zandatsu round will give you the possibility of combo-snagging multiple energy cells and get an increased amount of upgrade points!

Comment: Thanks for being specific! Though I think the rectangle marking the fuel cell is red instead of blue.

Comment: It is a red rectangle btw

Comment: Sorry, I changed it

Comment: @Xavier_Ex please check the additional paragraph

Answer (score 4):

From what I can tell, cutting off the **right arm** gives you 50 extra points, the **left arm** awards 100 points, and cutting through the guts (marked in red) lets you recover health and focus.

Comment: So I think the most effective method is to cut off the left arm, right arm, and the spine in one strike?

Comment: @Xavier_Ex Yes, though you are allowed to make as many cuts as you like until the body hits the ground or you run out of focus. Cutting through all 3 in a single cut is not always easy, since they aren't always aligned properly.

Comment: Too many cuts will "DESTROY" the body and earn you 100 points ONCE.

Answer (score 2):

Gathering Left Hands unlocks bonus items.

> Three different Wigs, unlocked every 10 Left Hands, which allow for infinite ammo, infinite fuel cells (and therefore infinite Ripper Mode and Blade Mode), and the ability for every slice to act as a Blade Mode slice, respectively. You'll also unlock other, less-cool items

To get the Left Hands, though, requires you to use Enhanced AR to reveal them, then Blade Mode to precision cut them. In some cases, you'll need to perform particular tasks to get the soldiers with Left Hands to appear.

As for getting the fuel cell, just aim for the red square. If you manage to cut multiple, you can grab multiple cells at once for big points!